# How to implement Dagger for worker classes?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Since the `Worker` class is created by the framework (`WorkerManager`), how can we use **@Inject** fields into the `Worker`?

Comment: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1183

Comment: I`d checked this link before I submit this question . Its not obvious the real implementation .
@Tuby

Comment: Just once look my sample https://github.com/saveendhiman/ComplexRecycler

Answer (score 3):

I am using [these](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe) series of post for implementing dagger in my app and `ProfileManager`
is the class I wnat to `inject` in my `Worker` class.

**UploadWorker**

```
public class UploadWorker extends Worker {

    @Inject
    ProfileManager profileManager;

    @Inject
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public UploadWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
     Provider.getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
     profileManager.someMethod();
    }

}
```

In **Application** class I am setting `Appcomponent` in my `Provider` class

```
   @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        Provider.setAppComponent(appComponent);
        return appComponent;
    }
```

**Provider**

```
public class Provider {

    private static AppComponent appComponent;

    public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }

    public static void setAppComponent(AppComponent component) {
        appComponent = component;
    }

}
```

**Appcomponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        ActivityBuilderModule.class,
        ApiModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        ViewModelModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    @Override
    void inject(DaggerApplication instance);

    void inject(MyApplication app);

    void inject(UploadWorker uploadWorker);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

}
```

Comment: While we start worker, it doesn't has constructor in it, how are you using this?

Comment: Why don't you create one?

Comment: I see it is overridden from parent. This solution works but have you seen the 'https://gist.github.com/ThePredators/1702e79c5d3860f415c542da446420eb'

it has different approach and plenty of work but didn't work for me. 
Any cons of your solution related to memory?

Comment: Sorry not familiar with this solution, I don't think there is any disadvantages with my solution.